# Applying CSS to a table using a SharePoint script editor

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What am I doing wrong with applying CSS to my table (Webpart: WebPartWPQ6) in SharePoint?

I have this script editor CSS (note the Font-size is just trying to see in an instant if what I apply works or not):

```
<style type="text/css">
  #WebPartTitleWPQ6 .ms-viewheadertr
  {
  font-size: 100px !important;
  }
</style>
```

I've tried replacing *ms-viewheartr* with *diidSort16RequestID*, *ms-headerSortTitleLink*, *ms-viewheadertr .ms-vhltr*, *ms-vhltrm*, *ms-vh-div*. But none of them seem to be working.

I'm getting the webpart name from inspecting the element:

```
<div id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6" class="ms-webpartzone-cell ms-webpart-cell-vertical ms-fullWidth s4-wpcell" onkeyup="WpKeyUp(event)" onmouseup="WpClick(event)">
        <div class="ms-webpart-chrome ms-webpart-chrome-vertical ms-webpart-chrome-fullWidth ">
            <div webpartid="69f4fe83-8a06-4eca-bbb2-fb143cdc2859" haspers="false" id="WebPartWPQ6"
```

and I'm trying to get the name of the header from:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any element with an id of `WebPartTitleWPQ6` in the HTML you posted. The closest thing is the element with the id `WebPartWPQ6`.

Try using a CSS selector of `#WebPartWPQ6` instead of `#WebPartTitleWPQ6`.